# Как найти в массиве объектов объект с нужным свойством(массив)?

Tags: javascript

```
{
  "result": [{
      "test": [{

          "name": "name1234"
          "id"    :   15
      }]
  },
      {
          "test": [{

              "name": "name23",
              "id"    :   14
          }, {

              "name": "name23",
              "id"    :   13
          }]
      }]
}
```

Получаю такую структуру данных . Массив result. Мне нужно в нем найти свойство «id» . Если есть хотя бы один id === 13, то возвращать true, иначе undefined
Как мне превратить эту структуру данных в массив значений id и уже в нем искать нужный id?

Comment: если просто найти `id` со значением `13` используйте цикл, `find`, а если получить массив с `id` то `map` и снова цикл или `find`. Здесь как бы основы языка нужно знать

Comment: А где в приведенном объекте хотя бы одно свойство `id`?

Comment: @Yaant его нету, а вдруг у него оно появится, непонятно что хотят на самом деле

Comment: Видимо имеется ввиду `primeLoyaltyId`

Comment: @Qwerty_Wasd автору вопроса бы основы подучить или выучить

Comment: извиняюсь. не тот массив скопировал

Answer (score 1):

Похитрил маленько -

```js
let a={
  "result": [
    {
      "test": [{
        "name": "name1234",
        "id"    :   15
      }]
    },
    {
      "test": [{

        "name": "name23",
        "id"    :   14
      }, {

        "name": "name23",
        "id"    :   13
      }]
    }
  ]
};
(JSON.stringify(a).replace(/["]/g,'').match(/(id:13\})|(id:13,)/g)) ? alert(true) : alert(undefined);
```

Comment: А если попадется `"id" : 1399999`?

Comment: @Yaant, Вы правы, не додумал )) Поправил ответ.

Answer (score 0):

вряд ли ты со стринги вытянешь массив объектов, да и зачем...

```
let a = {
  'result': [{
      'test': [{
          'name': "name1234",
          'id': 15
      }]
  },
      {
          'test': [{

              'name': "name23",
              'id'    :   14
          }, {

              'name': "name23",
              'id'    :   13
          }]
      }]
}
let b = []
Object.values(a.result).forEach((i) => {
   Object.values(i).forEach((j) => {
      for (let a in j) {
         if(j[a].hasOwnProperty('id')) {
            b[j[a].id] = j[a].name;
         }  
      }
   })
})
```

Далее в b записан массив, ключи которого это бывшие id, а значения - names(согласно заданию, если я правильно понял).
можно вместо b[j[a].id] = j[a].name; использовать b.push(j[a]); так будет нагляднее и b.length будет соответствовать действительности, но id будут раскиданы не по порядку.